# How to perform replace in a loop in js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, replace

I have a string like this

```
var string = '<img src="test.jpg'><img src="test2.jpg>';
var dom = new JSDOM(string,{ includeNodeLocations: true });
dom = dom.window.document.querySelectorAll("img");
for(var i = 0;i< dom.length;i++) {
    text = string.replace(/<img[^>]*>/g,'<amp-img layout="responsive" class="ampimageheight" src="'+dom[i].getAttribute('src')+'"  width="200" height= "100"></amp-img>');
 }
```

But my output is

```
<amp-img layout="responsive" class="ampimageheight" src="test2.jpg"  width="200" height= "100"></amp-img><amp-img layout="responsive" class="ampimageheight" src="test2.jpg"  width="200" height= "100"></amp-img>
```

In which only the second image src is replaced for 2 imags.I think this is because of the asynchronous.Can anyone please help me.Thanks.

Comment: `text` appears `undefined` to me...

Comment: Maybe this could work if you don't make the regex global. But then it's still a bit of an odd way of doing this.

Comment: @Rayon,I edited my code.

Comment: @Cerbrus,can you please suggest the better way.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you run `replace` in a loop, you don't need set the Regex's flag.
Because that replace all `img` when first time loop. 
After first loop is do nothing.
So, you can remove Regex flag, or use a callback replace your function's second arguments, like this.

```
text = string.replace(/<img[^>]*>/g, function(str, index){
return '<amp-img layout="responsive" class="ampimageheight" src="'+dom[index].getAttribute('src')+'"  width="200" height= "100"></amp-img>'
});
```

And it doesn't need loop;

Comment: It says DOM is undefined.

Comment: I don't know the return of the function `JSDOM`;
You try to console.log `dom` before run replace, And see it's right ?